# Is there a specific word or term for when ordinarily sensible people express hysterical or irrational ideas?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

I'm looking for something that adequately encapsulates the phenomenon of people who may be renowned in their field or society for their calm expertise and usually reasonable comments, but expresses hysterical or irrational thoughts on one or two pervasive issues (e.g. something political).

A sample sentence might be "David has a reputation for writing thoughtful commentary on all manner of social issues, but has showed unusual signs of [mystery word] when writing about molehills lately".

Comment: 'Uncharacteristic' comes to mind.

Comment: An idiomatic expression that might work is "lost it". The 'it' is not specified but will be assumed to mean something like 'reason' or 'common sense'. It is quite informal but conveys hysterical more than uncharacteristic.

Comment: 'Take leave of his/her senses' would also work. You might consider rephrasing the sentence as follows: 

'David has a reputation for writing thoughtful commentary on all manner of social issues, but seems to have taken leave of his senses when writing about molehills lately.'

Comment: It would probably only work in your specific example (if at all), but maybe you could consider playing off the “making mountains out of molehills” idiom with: “… but has showed unusual signs of orogeny/mountain-making when writing about molehills lately."

Comment: Isn't this the definition of "political"?

Comment: I think the kind of word you might be after is: histrionics or theatrics. Personally, since I don't care about being PC, I would say: hysteria.

Answer (score 2):

The first English (sporting) idiom that sprang to my mind is ***dropping the ball***, suggesting that they're being clumsy. It's possibly not *quite* what you wanted, so a few others:

- Less colloquially than *dropping the ball* is just ***losing their way***.
- Simply *signs of **craziness***, ***madness*** or ***obsession***
- *... signs of **joining the lunatic fringe***
- *... signs of **senility***

Comment: @andy-semyonov may I incorporate your comment as additional material, with attribution?

Comment: Someone seems to be on a down-voting spree.

Answer (score -1):

The British have always had myriad words.  My favorite:

'but seems to have become somewhat a **howler** when writing about molehills lately.'

absurdness, craziness, foolishness, inaneness, madness, senselessness, witlessness, buffoonery, monkeyshine(s), shenanigan(s), tomfoolery drivel, humbug, nonsense, twaddle blunder, bungle, flub, goof, howler

and

dotty, fey, loopy, off, potty [chiefly British], teched (or tetched), touched aberrant, delirious, delusional, delusionary, disordered, disturbed, neurotic, obsessive-compulsive, paranoiac (also paranoic), paranoid (also paranoidal), schizoid, schizophrenic, sociopathic, eccentric, odd, oddball, pixilated (also pixillated), queer, strange, foolish, senseless, witless, irrational, unreasonable, amok (or amuck), ape, ballistic, bananas, berserk, nuclear, distracted, distraught, frantic, frenzied, haywire, hysterical (also hysteric), raving, wigged-out
, fixated, monomaniac, monomaniacal, obsessed Phrases around the bend, off one's gourd, off one's head, off one's rocker, out of one's head (or mind), out to lunch [slang]

all from https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/senseless idiot and insane lol

Comment: A *howler* refers to the original sense of *lunatic*, i.e. *barking at the moon*. :o)

Comment: That's why i like it.  My English grandfather used it frequently when his progeny on occasion did not make sense: 'You are howling at the moon'.

Comment: I'm British and I've never heard 'howler' used like that. The only meaning I know for 'a howler' (apart from a howler monkey) is a childish, gross and obvious error, usually in an education context.

Comment: Translators talk about howlers, too.  Howler is a funny mistake. It makes you howl with laughter. And it ain't gonna cut it here. I see no reason to list a bunch of words without rhyme or reason.

Comment: +1, it's not a *great* answer. And I did a double take on *howler* too.

Comment: +1, but I think your Grandfather's full "howling at the moon" (or just "moon-howling" for short) would fit better/be clearer: (" ,,,but has showed unusual signs of **howling at the moon/moon-howling**" when writing about molehills lately."